# Image of the boundary maps in the homological spectral sequence of a filtration of a chain complex

Tags: homological-algebra, spectral-sequences

I'm trying to understand the construction of the homological spectral sequence of a filtration given in C.A.Weibel ''An introduction to homological algebra''. Here, they start with a filtration of a chain complex $(C,d)$:
$$\emptyset=F_{-1}C\subset F_0C\subset F_1C\subset\dots\subset F_nC=C$$
They define the set $A_p^r=\lbrace c\in F_pC\mid d(c)\in F_{p-r}C\rbrace$ and in the proof of Lemma 5.4.7 it is stated that $\text{Im}(d^r_p)=\frac{A_r^p}{A^{r+1}_p+A^{r-1}_{p-1}}$· My question is the following:

Say $A_p^r$ encode the elements of $F_pC$ that go down $\geq r$ steps, when quotienting with $A^{r+1}_p+A^{r-1}_{p-1}$ we are killing the elements of $F_pC$ that go down $\geq r+1$ steps and the elements of $F_{p-1}C$ that go down $\geq r-1$ steps. Hence $\text{Im}(d^r_p)$ encode the elements of $F_pC\setminus F_{p-1}C$ that go down exactly $r$ steps, i.e:
$$\text{Im}(d^r_p)=\lbrace c\in F_pC\setminus F_{p-1}\mid d(c)\in F_{p-r}C\setminus F_{p-r-1}C\rbrace$$
I am not sure this is right, since it seems a pretty easy formula for a difficult object. So, my question is whether this formula is right or not and, if not, how one can do to explicitly compute the images in an actual example.

Comment: Your proposed formula doesn't make much sense. (For example, the image of any map should contain zero, right?) If you'd like to get your hands on some examples, you could try my macaulay2 package. Here is the page that explains how to compute the spectral sequence of a filtered complex: https://jwiltshiregordon.github.io/ExactCouples/html/_exact__Couple.html

Comment: @JohnWiltshire-Gordon Yeah, I know that the formula doesn't have much sense. However, I don't know what I did wrong in my derivation.

Comment: Your derivation imagines that all these groups are free abelian and that you can just keep track of generating sets. (But abelian groups don't work that way!) I still recommend doing examples.

Comment: I can write something like an answer if you'd like, but the main issue with your proposed formula is sort of a category error. Your quotation from Weibel is a subquotient of C, but the claimed equivalent set you provide lies in C itself. It would at best be a set of representatives for the nonzero classes in the quotient. If you've quoted correctly, it is: the idea is right, but the levels are mixed up.